How can I terminate threads without waiting for them to finish?
I have a complex application involving multiple threads, using both QThreads (from PyQt/PySide) and Python's threading module. The complexity stems from either the nature of the problem or the approach I've taken to solve it.
The application has a UI with a "Stop" button, and I need a way to instantly stop all running threads when this button is pressed. I want to avoid adding numerous stop flags and managing their state across all nested threads. The goal is to allow users to stop all operations with a single action, so they can make changes and restart the processes as needed.
Is there a method or approach to achieve this kind of instantaneous thread termination?

There is no API to forcibly kill a thread. The thread must end its execution. In other words, you need to design the code that runs in your threads to accomplish this. The thread should be actively checking for stop signals, which can be designed in many different ways. There are many StackOverflow questions that cover such methods. It may help if you can share some code of the things you have tried, what's not working, etc.

Lets say I have two Qthreads. One for the main and other for logging. Inside the main I have another two threads. One for a syringe pump and another for all the 4 different task that the device can do.  All these tasks have also threads. Flagging everything will kinda be a mess, i think. And waiting for the threads to finish until the Qthread starts again is almost impossible because it might happen that somehow the device starts working in the wrong location, the thread will get stuck. So the only solution i have right now is the flags but i dont like it.

Re, "...numerous stop flags..." Why would you need more than one flag? Why can't all of the threads watch the same single flag?

Your threads will need to watch for some sort of stop flag, but as @SolomonSlow points out in a comment, you only need a single flag. They can all watch the same one.
Consider the following code; it starts up an arbitrary number of threads (5 by default) all watching the same threading.Event object; setting the object will cause all of the threads to exit:
import argparse
import time
import logging
import random
import threading

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, jobId, stopFlag):
        self.jobId = jobId
        self.stopFlag = stopFlag
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        LOG.info("starting job %s", self.jobId)

        while not self.stopFlag.wait(timeout=random.randint(1, 10)):
            LOG.info("doing some work in job %s", self.jobId)

        LOG.info("all done with job %s", self.jobId)


def parse_args():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    p.add_argument("-n", "--num-threads", type=int, default=5)

    return p.parse_args()


def main():
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(asctime)s %(message)s", datefmt="%H:%M:%S"
    )

    args = parse_args()
    stopFlag = threading.Event()

    tasks = []
    for i in range(args.num_threads):
        t = Worker(i, stopFlag)
        tasks.append(t)
        t.start()

    time.sleep(30)
    LOG.info("sending stop signal")
    stopFlag.set()
    for t in tasks:
        t.join()

    LOG.info("all done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Running this looks something like:
10:45:28 starting job 0
10:45:28 starting job 1
10:45:28 starting job 2
10:45:28 starting job 3
10:45:28 starting job 4
10:45:29 doing some work in job 1
10:45:29 doing some work in job 4
10:45:32 doing some work in job 3
10:45:33 doing some work in job 0
10:45:35 doing some work in job 0
10:45:38 doing some work in job 2
10:45:38 doing some work in job 1
.
.
.
10:45:52 doing some work in job 1
10:45:55 doing some work in job 4
10:45:57 doing some work in job 2
10:45:58 sending stop signal
10:45:58 all done with job 3
10:45:58 all done with job 2
10:45:58 all done with job 4
10:45:58 all done with job 1
10:45:58 all done with job 0
10:45:58 all done


and I need a way to instantly stop all running threads when this button is pressed

"Instantly" is tricky, and really depends on what the code in your threads looks like. In the example here, the threads do exit pretty much instantly, but that's because they spend the bulk of their time simply waiting for the stop flag. If your threads are doing lots of work between checks of the stop flag, that's going to impact the amount of time it takes them to respond when you press the STOP button.
If your threads spend a bunch of time waiting on file descriptors, then instead of using a threading.Event object, you may want to just create pipe and close it when you want things to stop. You can then watch it in the same select/poll loop you're using for handling file or network i/o:
import os
import argparse
import select
import time
import logging
import random
import threading

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, jobId, stopFlag):
        self.jobId = jobId
        self.stopFlag = stopFlag
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        LOG.info("starting job %s", self.jobId)

        poll = select.poll()
        poll.register(self.stopFlag, select.POLLHUP)

        while True:
            events = poll.poll(1000 * random.randint(1, 10))
            for fd, event in events:
                if fd == self.stopFlag:
                    break
            else:
                LOG.info("doing some work in job %s", self.jobId)
                continue
            break

        LOG.info("all done with job %s", self.jobId)


def parse_args():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    p.add_argument("-n", "--num-threads", type=int, default=5)
    p.add_argument("-w", "--wait", type=int, default=30)

    return p.parse_args()


def main():
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(asctime)s %(message)s", datefmt="%H:%M:%S"
    )

    args = parse_args()
    stopFlag = os.pipe()

    tasks = []
    for i in range(args.num_threads):
        t = Worker(i, stopFlag[0])
        tasks.append(t)
        t.start()

    time.sleep(args.wait)
    LOG.info("sending stop signal")
    os.close(stopFlag[1])
    for t in tasks:
        t.join()

    LOG.info("all done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

